# jQuery : selects each element with different specific attributes

Tags: jquery, attributes, jquery-selectors

I need to target au links which have `target=_blank` and which are not .pdf file.

For now, i am doing this which works fine :

```
$('a[target=_blank]').click(function (e) {
 if (this.href.split('.').pop() !== 'pdf') {
     // do something
 }
});
```

I was wondering if it is possible to use the jQuery `[attribute$=value]` selector : `$("a[href$='.pdf']")` something like :

```
("a[href$!='.pdf']")
```

I ask because i find this syntax really simple to use.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`:not()` selector](https://api.jquery.com/not-selector/)

```
$('a[target=_blank]:not([href$=".pdf"])')
```

Comment: Thanx ! Even if my code works fine, I think  it is a better choice to use `:not() selector` because it is more readable